# Insert code for only first queried row then nothing

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I need the first `class` to be *active* and then empty from then on.

```
<?       
    $slidesinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slides ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 4");
    while ($slidesingo = mysql_fetch_array($slidesinfo)) 
    { 
    ?> 
      <li class="active"><span><? echo $slidesingo['title'] ?></span></li>
    <? 
     } 
?>
```

So the result should be:

```
<li class="active"><span>Title 1</span></li>
<li><span>Title 2</span></li>
<li><span>Title 3</span></li>
<li><span>Title 4</span></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code.

```
$i = 1;
while ($slidesingo = mysql_fetch_array($slidesinfo)) 
{ 
    $cls = "";
    if($i==1)
    {
        $cls = "active";
        $i++;
    }
    ?> 
        <li class="<?php echo $cls;?>"><span><? echo $slidesingo['title'] ?></span></li>
    <?              
} 
?>
```